# Emberjs - mapping JSON to model fields

Tags: json, ember.js

My client API return JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "Result": [
        {
            "member": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mark Smith",
                "email_address": "name@email.com",
                "member_type": [
                    "Premium"
                ],
                "privileges": [
                    "MEMBER"
                ]
            },
            "activites": {
                "ActivityId": "15",
                "ActivityName": "Tennie"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ResultCount": 1 
}
```

Which I need to map to my Ember app model:

```
App.Member = DS.Model.extend({                                                                             
  memberid:             DS.attr('number'),
  membername:          DS.attr('string'),
  memberemail:        DS.attr('string'),
  membertype:          DS.attr('string'),
  memberprivileges:         DS.attr('number'),
  activityID:           DS.attr('number')
});                                                                                                          


App.MemberSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({                                                                  
extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType){         
...
```

I've tried to implement a Serializer to map fields between the json and the app model but not sure how to do so using extractArray as I couldn't find any tutorial / example on how to do so, so can someone please provide me with example on how to do so based on my client JSON structure?

Additions I've made based on James reply:

```
App.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function (serialized) {
    return (Ember.typeOf(serialized) == "array")
      ? serialized
      : []
  },

  serialize: function (deserialized) {
    var type = Ember.typeOf(deserialized)
    if (type == 'array') {
      return deserialized
    } else if (type == 'string') {
      return deserialized.split(',').map(function (item) {
        return jQuery.trim(item)
      });
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
})


App.register("transform:array", DS.ArrayTransform);

App.Member = DS.Model.extend({                                                                             
    cont : DS.attr('array')    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make and use your own DS.Model object for array

```
/**
 * Configure a transform for DS.Model Arrays
 * DS.attr('array')
 */
App.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function (serialized) {
    return (Ember.typeOf(serialized) == "array")
      ? serialized
      : []
  },

  serialize: function (deserialized) {
    var type = Ember.typeOf(deserialized)
    if (type == 'array') {
      return deserialized
    } else if (type == 'string') {
      return deserialized.split(',').map(function (item) {
        return jQuery.trim(item)
      });
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks James for your answer, I've updated my question with changes I've made based on your answer in addition to some references I've found recommending registering the transform, but error now: TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `transform:array`....if I remove the transform registration, I get another error: "Error while loading route: undefined" so any thoughts what I am doing wrong here and how to fix? Thanks for your time

Comment: actually you don't need to use DS.Model('array'), it should work fine just using DS.Model()

Comment: I am using DS.attr('array') not DS.Model('array') and even with DS.attr() either case I am still getting errors mentioned in my previous comment :)

Comment: sorry. I'll have to look into the issue a bit more because that works on my app. Could you make a jsfiddle? Also, what ember version are you using?

Comment: Sure, will post code on jsfiddle and paste link here, I am using Ember 1.3

Comment: Here is the link in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HSmLU/ Thanks for your time and efforts

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
App.Member = DS.Model.extend({                                                                             
    memberid: DS.attr('number'),
    membername: DS.attr('string'),
    memberemail: DS.attr('string'),
    membertype: DS.attr('string'),
    memberprivileges: DS.attr('number'),
    activityID: DS.attr('number')
});                                                                                                          


App.MemberSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    attrs: {
        memberid: 'id',
        membername: 'name',
        memberemail: 'email',
        membertype: 'type',
        memberprivileges: 'privileges',
        activityID: 'ActivityId'
    }
});
```